# Fusion law for foldr1?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

For `foldr` we have the *fusion law*: if `f` is strict, `f a = b`, and

`f (g x y) = h x (f y)` for all `x, y`, then `f . foldr g a = foldr h b`.

How can one discover/derive a similar law for `foldr1`?  (It clearly can't even take the same form - consider the case when both sides act on `[x]`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use free theorems to derive statements like the fusion law. The [Automatic generation of free theorems](http://www-ps.iai.uni-bonn.de/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi) does this work for you, it automatically derives the following statement if you enter `foldr1` or the type `(a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a`.

If `f` strict and `f (p x y) = q (f x) (f y))` for all `x` and `y` you have `f (foldr1 p z) = foldr1 q (map f z))`. That is, in contrast to you statement about `foldr` you get an additional `map f` on the right hand side.

Also note that the free theorem for `foldr` is slightly more general than your fusion law and, therefore, looks quite similar to the law for `foldr1`. Namely you have for strict functions `g` and `f` if `g (p x y) = q (f x) (g y))` for all `x` and `y` then `g (foldr p z v) = foldr q (g z) (map f v))`.

Comment: It's been some time since I've looked at the technical details of "theorems for free". Does it account for functions which may call `undefined` (as `foldr1` must)?

Comment: Free theorems consider the case that polymorphic functions use `undefined`. In the case of `foldr1` it is accounted by the requirement that `f` has to be strict. In fact, Philip Wadler already observed this requirement in his original paper about free theorems. In the automatic generation website you get these additional conditions for `undefined` by using the option "general recursion but no selective strictness". You can also consider the presence of the strict evaluation primitive `seq` by using the option "general recursion and selective strictness".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's going to be anything satisfying for `foldr1`. [I think] It's just defined as

```
foldr1 f (x:xs) = foldr f x xs
```

let's first expand what you have above to work on the entire list,

```
f (foldr g x xs) = foldr h (f x) xs
```

for foldr1, you could say,

```
f (foldr1 g xs) = f (foldr g x xs)
= foldr h (f x) xs
```

to recondense into foldr1, you can create some imaginary function that maps `f` to the left element, for a result of,

```
f . foldr1 g = foldr1 h (mapfst f) where
    mapfst (x:xs) = f x : xs
```

Comment: Unfortunately your definition of `foldr1` is not quite correct if `f` isn't associative: consider `foldr1 (-) [3,4,5]` vs `foldr (-) 3 [4,5]`, for instance.