# Haskell - How to transform maximum (xs ++ map (x+) xs) to max (maximum xs) (x + maximum xs)

Tags: haskell, equational-reasoning

One of the excercises in "Thinking Functionally With Haskell" is about making a program more efficient using the fusion law. I am having some trouble trying to replicate the answer.

A part of the calculation requires that you transform `maximum (xs ++ map (x+) xs)` to `max (maximum xs) (x + maximum xs)` through equational reasoning.

`maximum` is defined as `foldr1 max` and as I don't know many rules surrounding foldr1 I'm stuck on even the first part which is to transform `foldr1 max (xs ++ map (x+) xs)` to `max (foldr1 max xs) (foldr1 max (map (x+) xs))` so that's the first thing I'd like to understand.

Once we get past that, the next part seems harder i.e. transforming `foldr1 max (map (x+) xs)` to `x + foldr1 max xs`.  Intuitively it makes sense; if you are finding the maximum value of a bunch of numbers that all have 'x' added to them then that's the same as finding the maximum of all the numbers before 'x' was added and adding 'x' to the result.

The only thing I've found to help me in this second stage is [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6812893/4275865)
where the answer is basically given to you (if you assume p = q) with no individual easy to understand steps as you normally see with equational reasoning.

So please could someone show me the steps to do the transformation ?

Comment: It doesn't include `foldl`, but [here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048281/haskell-how-to-transform-map-sum-map-x-xss-to-map-x-map-sum-xss/27048468#27048468) I wrote the other day that uses equational reasoning for a similar problem.

Comment: The main point you are missing in both this question and in your other question is the use of _induction_ to prove statements about lists.

Most statements about lists can be proved in a straight-forward way by induction. See section 13.5 of [this chapter](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/chapter13.pdf) for more details about induction on lists.

Comment: @bheklilr yes, that was my other question and I loved your answer; it was exactly what I was looking for so, thank you again. I did really try to think this new one through before asking but I couldn't find the right laws to help me. Maybe this one isn't so straight-forward.

Comment: @user5402 thanks, I do know (a little) about induction and to be fair to me the previous question was not solved with it. Rather it was solved with the eta reduce and expand trick and the compostition law of map. What I've seen with induction is that you get to a certain point you feel you can't simplify or change further and then you use induction to prove the two sides are equal.  It takes a certain amount of confidence to know you can't reduce further and that you should switch to induction. That's the confidence I don't have yet.

Comment: But how do you prove the composition law for `map`? Everything about lists boils down to an induction proof. A video which may help with understanding induction: [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/seq_induction/proof_by_induction/v/proof-by-induction)

Comment: @BarryRogerson to use induction you need to figure out how you get more complex solution from a simpler one. So, you assume the simplest case, prove it works (eg empty list). Then you get the case just one step harder (eg a list with one element) - just to see that it works. Then you generalize the proof for the latter case to use the solution for the smaller case - eg use the proof for empty list to help prove the case with the list with one element. Then you know you can take the proof for any shorter list to prove the case for a longer list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be seen by induction.

Suppose, `xs == []`. Both expressions are true, since both yield `error`.

Suppose, `xs == [y]`

```
maximum([y]++map(x+)[y]) == -- by definition of map
                         == maximum([y]++[x+y])
                            -- by definition of ++
                         == maximum([y,x+y])
                            -- by definition of maximum
                         == foldr1 max [y,x+y]
                            -- by definition of foldr1
                         == max y (foldr1 max [x+y])
                            -- by definition of foldr1
                         == max y (x+y)
                            -- by definition of foldr1 and maximum [y]
                         == max (maximum [y]) (x+maximum [y])
```

Next, we will need a proof of commutativity of `maximum`: `maximum (xs++(y:ys)) == max y (maximum (xs++ys))` - you will notice this is needed, if you skip this proof and go straight to the proof of `maximum (y:ys ++ map(x+)(y:ys))` - one step there requires to move `(x+y)` from the middle of the list `ys++(x+y):map(x+)ys`.

Suppose, `xs==[]`:

```
maximum ([]++(y:ys)) == maximum (y:ys)
                     -- by definition of foldr1 and maximum
                     == max y (maximum ys)
                     == max y (maximum ([]++ys))
```

Suppose, `xs==x:xx`:

```
maximum(x:xx++(y:ys)) == maximum (x:(xx++(y:ys)))
                     -- by definition of foldr1 and maximum
                      == max x (maximum (xx++(y:ys)))
                     -- by induction
                      == max x (max y (maximum (xx++ys)))
 -- by commutativity of max, max a (max b c) == max b (max a c)
                      == max y (max x (maximum (xx++ys)))
                     -- by definition of foldr1 and maximum
                      == max y (maximum (x:(xx++ys)))
                     -- by definition of ++
                      == max y (maximum ((x:xx) ++ ys))
```

Ok, now get back to proving the original statement.
Now, suppose `xs == y:ys`

```
 maximum (y:ys ++ map(x+)(y:ys)) ==
 -- by definition of map
                         == maximum(y:ys ++ (x+y):map(x+)ys)
 -- by definition of foldr1 and maximum
                         == max y (maximum(ys ++ (x+y):map(x+)ys)
 -- by commutativity of maximum
                         == max y (max (x+y) (maximum (ys++map(x+)ys)))
 -- by induction, (maximum (ys++map(x+)ys)) == max (maximum ys) (x+maximum ys))
                         == max y (max (x+y) 
                                       (max (maximum ys) (x+maximum ys)))
 -- by commutativity of max (ie max a (max b c) == max b (max a c))
                         == max y (max (maximum ys) 
                                       (max (x+y) (x+maximum ys)))
 -- by associativity of max (is max a (max b c) == max (max a b) c)
                         == max (max y (maximum ys))
                                       (max (x+y) (x+maximum ys)))
                         -- by definition of max, max (x+y) (x+z) == x+(max y z)
                         == max (max y (maximum ys))
                                       (x + max y (maximum ys)))
                         -- by definition of foldr1 and maximum
                         == max (maximum (y:ys)) (x + maximum (y:ys))
```

---

Since you asked also about induction and how to see a certain thing can be proven by induction, here's some more.

You can see some of the steps are "by definition" - we know they are true by looking at how the function is written. For example, `maximum = foldr1 max` and `foldr1 f (x:xs) = f x $ foldr1 f xs` for non-empty `xs`. Definition of some other things are less clear - `max y z` the definition of `max` is not shown; yet, it can be shown by induction that `max (x+y)(x+z) == x+max y z`. Here one would start with the definition of `max 0 y == y`, then how to work out `max` for greater `x`. (Then you'd also need to cover the cases for negative `x` and `y` in a similar way.)

For example, natural numbers are zero and any successor of a natural number. You see, here we don't have any comparison defined, nothing. So, the properties of addition, subtraction, max, etc, stem *from the definition* of the functions:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat -- zero and any successor of a natural number
(+) :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat -- addition is...
Z + x = x -- adding zero is neutral
(S x) + y = S (x + y) -- recursive definition of (1+x)+y = 1+(x+y)
-- here unwittingly we introduced associativity of addition:
-- (x+y)+z=x+(y+z)
-- so, let's see the simplest case:
-- x == Z
-- (Z+y)+z == -- by definition, Z+y=y -- see the first line of (+)
--         == y+z
--         == Z+(y+z) -- by definition, Z+(y+z)=(y+z)
--
-- ok, now try x == S m
-- (S m + y) + z == -- by definition, (S m)+y=S(m+y) -- see the second line of(+)
--               == S (m+y) + z
--               == S ((m+y)+z) -- see the second line of (+)
--                                 - S (m+y) + z = S ((m+y)+z)
--               == S (m+(y+z)) -- by induction, the simpler
--                                 case of (m+y)+z=m+(y+z)
--                                 is known to be true
--               == (S m)+(y+z) -- by definition, see second line of (+)
-- proven
```

Then, because we don't have comparison of Nats yet, have to define `max` in a particular way.

```
max :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
max Z y = y -- we know Z is not the max
max x Z = x -- and the other way around, too
-- this inadvertently introduced commutativity of max already

max (S x) (S y) = S (max x y) -- this inadvertently introduces the law
-- that max (x+y) (x+z) == x + (max y z)
```

Suppose, we want to prove the latter.
Assume `x == Z`

```
max (Z+y) (Z+z) == -- by definition of (+)
                == max y z
                == Z + (max y z) -- by definition of (+)
```

ok, now assume `x == S m`

```
max ((S m) + y) ((S m)+z) == -- by definition of (+)
                == max (S(m+y)) (S(m+z))
                -- by definition of max
                == S (max (m+y) (m+z))
                -- by induction
                == S (m+(max y z))
                -- by definition of (+)
                == (S m)+(max y z)
```

So, you see, it is important to know the definitions, important to prove the simplest case, and important to use the proof for the simpler case in the slightly more complex case.

Comment: This is really nice.  It seems like the spark of genius in this is knowing that you needed to prove the commutativity of maximum for one of the steps.  How did you know you needed that ? Was it based on something you've seen or done before ?

Comment: @BarryRogerson good question. It comes from induction. Once you attempt to prove by induction, which is typically done by induction on list size, you will see that to get a proof for a longer list (`maximum ([x,y]++[x,y])`) from a proof for a shorter list (`maximum ([y]++[y]`) you need to be able to move `x` outside the `maximum`. You can see that the first `x` can be moved by definition of `foldr1` (so you get `max x (maximum ([y]++[x,y]))`), but the second `x` is in the middle of the list, so you need a special proof for that.

Answer (score 2):

A sketch:

```
maximum (xs ++ map (x+) xs)
foldr1 max (xs ++ map (x+) xs)
foldr max (foldr1 max xs) (map (x+) xs)
foldr max (maximum xs) (map (x+) xs)
max (maximum xs) (foldr1 max (map (x+) xs))
max (maximum xs) (x + foldr1 max xs)
max (maximum xs) (x + maximum xs)
```

using (there may be weaker assumptions, I picked what worked)

```
0. xs, ys are nonempty
1. f is commutative and associative
A. foldr1 f (xs ++ ys) == foldr f (foldr1 f xs) ys
B. foldr f s xs = f s (foldr1 f xs)
C. foldr1 f (map g xs) = g (foldr1 f xs)
  if f (g x) (g y) == g (f x y)
```

The proofs of the lemmata follow by induction.
First, let's remember our definitions:

```
foldr k z  []    = z
foldr k z (x:xs) = k x (foldr k z xs)

foldr1 k [z]    = z
foldr1 k (x:xs) = k x (foldr1 k xs)

map k [] = []
map k (x:xs) = k x : map k xs
```

Then, for A:

```
To show: foldr1 f (xs ++ ys) == foldr f (foldr1 f xs) ys
Induction on xs.
Base case: xs = [x]
    foldr1 f ([x] ++ ys) == f x (foldr1 f ys)
    Induction on ys: ys = [y]
        == f x (foldr f [y]) = f x y = f y x 
        == foldr f x [y] = foldr f (foldr1 f [x]) [y]
    Step. ys = (y:yy)
        == f x (foldr1 f (y:yy)) 
        == f x (f y (foldr1 f yy))  -> associativity and commutativity
        == f y (f x (foldr1 f yy))  -> induction assumption
        == f y (foldr f x yy)
        == foldr f (foldr1 f [x]) (y:yy)
Step: xs = (x:xx)
    foldr1 f (x:xx ++ ys) = f x (foldr1 f (xx ++ yy)) 
        == f x (fold f (foldr1 f xx) yy)
        == fold f (foldr1 f xx) (x:yy)
    Induction on ys.
    Base case ys = [y]
        == f x (f y (foldr1 f xx)) == f y (f x (foldr1 f (x:xx)) 
        == fold f (foldr1 f xs) [y]
    Step. ys = (y:yy)
        == f x (f y (fold f (foldr1 f xx) yy) -> associativity, commutativity
        == f y (f x (fold f (foldr1 f xx) yy) -> induction assumption
        == f y (fold f (foldr1 f (x:xx) yy)
        == fold f (foldr1 f xs) ys
```

And so on, try it yourself.